# storing multiples values for particular key in an array of dictionaries not working iOS

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, key-value, nsmutabledictionary

i want to have an array which stores dictionaries with some key-value pair like shown below.

```
add =     (
            {
        ans = abc;
        que = Fdgdf;
    },
            {
        ans = hi;
        que = hello;
    },
            {
        ans = GM;
        que = dosa;
    }
)
```

Here is what i tried.

```
for (int i=0; i<=[addKeyArray count]; i++) {

        [_addDictNewQA setObject:[addKeyarray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"que"];
        [_addDictNewQA setObject:[addValuesArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"ans"];
[_addArrayNewQA addObject:_addDictNewQA];
                }
```

here addKeyArray is the array which holds all the 'que'  elements and addValuesArrray holds all the 'and' elements. but when i set these arrays to dictionary objects and add that dictionary to new array(_addArrayNewQA), it only display the last element like this-

```
 add =     (
        {
    ans = GM;
    que = dosa;
},
        {
   ans = GM;
    que = dosa;
},
        {
    ans = GM;
    que = dosa;
}
)
```

Can anyone please tell me whats wrong in my code. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are setting values in same object of `NSMutableDictionary`, also you dont need to have the NSMutableDictionary as global as you are using it in the for loop only.

You need to create new dictionary

```
 for (int i=0; i<=[addKeyArray count]; i++) {
    NSMutableDictionary *_addDictNewQA = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [_addDictNewQA setObject:[addKeyarray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"que"];
    [_addDictNewQA setObject:[addValuesArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"ans"];
}
[_addArrayNewQA addObject:_addDictNewQA];
```

Comment: Rest all thanks for your help and time. It helps a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new inner dictionary each iteration.  What you are doing is adding the same dictionary over and over and changing its contents so you end up with an array of dictionaries containing the last entry.

```
for (int i=0; i<=[addKeyArray count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *innerDict = @{
        @"que" : addKeyArray[i],
        @"ans" : addValuesArray[i]
    };
    [_addArrayNewQA addObject:innerDict];
}
```

And remove the `_addDictNewQA` instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

Create dictionary in for loop. you need to create new dictionary every time. So, create mutable dictionary in for loop and add that dictionary to mutable array (your result array) which must not create (alloc and init) in for loop.

Your code seems that you have created your dictionary outside the for loop.!!